# Why saturate in Unreal material is considered as free in modern graphics hardware

Tags: shader, unreal-engine4

The [`saturate`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/Materials/ExpressionReference/Math#saturate) node (clamping another material expression (1 or more floats) between 0 and 1) within [UnrealEngine material expressions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/Materials/ExpressionReference) is documented with

> Saturate is free on most modern graphics hardware

[image: Saturate node in UE material editor]

This node is translated to shaders in `UMaterialExpressionSaturate::Compile`, which uses `FMaterialUniformExpressionSaturate`. There, the clamping of the expression happens with

```
static FORCEINLINE T Clamp( const T X, const T Min, const T Max )
{
    return X<Min ? Min : X<Max ? X : Max;
}
```

However, I didn't find the translation into the shader of the respective platform (e.g. HLSL).

1. Are the shaders in UE4 compiled with `FMaterialCompiler`?
2. How does the resulting code look like (e.g. in HLSL) for that clamp function? Why is the instruction cost almost free?

Answer (score 3):

That is because clamp(), abs() and negation operation might be instruction modifiers on certain GPU platforms. AFAIK, clamp() modifier is supported by all modern hardware.

Instruction modifiers affect the result of the instruction before it is written into the destination register. From the point of view of instruction set, to have an instruction with modifier means to have two different instructions (for example, **add** and **add_sat**).